# Why is `inject` very slow?

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

Here is the benchmark

```
require 'benchmark'

# create random array
arr = 40000.times.map { rand(100000).to_s }

r1 = ''
r2 = ''
r3 = ''

Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report {
        r1 = (arr.map { |s|
            "[#{s}]"
        }).join
    }

    x.report {
        r2 = arr.inject('') { |memo, s|
            memo + "[#{s}]"
        }
    }

    x.report {
        r3 = ''
        arr.each { |s|
            r3 << "[#{s}]"
        }
    }
end

# confirm result is same
puts r1 == r2
puts r2 == r3
```

Here is result

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046875)
   5.031000   0.844000   5.875000 (  5.875000)
   0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
true
true
```

Has any way to make `inject` faster ?

Comment: If you code `memo << "[#{s}]"` instead of `memo +` there will be another result ;)

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev: good one!

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev: nice, so we better use `append` instead of `concat` if we can =)

Comment: @Wing: That would be a wrong conclusion (dropping functional in favour of imperative programming for a premature optimization). Your first `map` snippet is perfectly fine -only slightly slower than using `each`- and I'd say it's the idiomatic way to do it in Ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my guess: unlike the two other methods, approach with `inject` keeps creating bigger and bigger strings. All of them (except the last) are temporary and will have to be garbage-collected. That's wasted memory and CPU right there. This is also a good example of [Shlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm).

> ... The inefficiency to which Spolsky was drawing an analogy was the poor programming practice of repeated concatenation of C-style null-terminated character arrays (that is, strings) in which the position of the destination string has to be recomputed from the beginning of the string each time because it is not carried over from a previous concatenation. ...

Approach with `map` creates many small strings, so, at least, it doesn't spend as much time allocating memory.

#### Update

As pointed out by Yevgeniy Anfilofyev in the comments, you can avoid creation of many big strings by not creating any. Just keep appending to the `memo`.

```
r2 = arr.inject('') { |memo, s|
  memo << "[#{s}]"
}
```

This works because both `String#+` and `String#<<` return a new value for the string.

Comment: Has any way to prevent allocate so much memory ?